# Implementing dynamic permission control library

Tags: c#, permissions, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I need to create permissions for Resources and determine who can **read, write or delete** them. These permissions could be in a database table and should be configurable with an Administrator. Then I want to check permissions in one centralized place (for example a filter attribute) like below:

```
    //Controller action method
    [HttpPut]
    [PermissionControlFilter]
    public ApiResultBase Update(PlanDTO model)
    {
        ...
    }

    // Filter attribute class
    public class PermissionControlFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var permissions = GetUserPermissions(User.Identity.Name);
            // check if the user has permission for the action and
            // can read, write or delete according to the model type
            // and rules defined for this model type
        }
    }
```

I need permissions to be defined for **User --> Resource** and **Claim --> Resource**.

One challenge might be how to define permissions when it comes to very detailed resources. For example how should I define a permission to deny a user from changing a specific field of an entity but allow changing the other fields.

My current requirement is for ASP.NET Web Api, but I'd rather use a solution that can be used in other applications too. I'm also willing to use claims based security if that's an important factor.